# Creating a letter in the terminal by entering

Tags: laravel, caching, terminal

By pressing the enter button in the terminal to execute commands, a letter is displayed and then the commands are executed. Also, this word is at the top of the page on all the pages of the website. What should I do to remove it?

To remove it, I have run all cache removal commands.
for example:
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
composer i